# Cleanup the [Userform] and [Userforms] tags

Tags: feature-request, support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Neither the [userform](/questions/tagged/userform) nor the [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) tags has very many questions posted to them, but they are currently two distinct tags.

Since they are obviously the same thing, can we combine them?

If not combine them, would it be more practical to simply remove the tags given their low usage and the very generic concept they represent?

---

Per [ThinkingStiff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141183/179372), I have cleaned up the miscellaneous questions. There are currently no questions for [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) (though nothing's stopping anyone from posting a new question tagged with this), and any tags for [userform](/questions/tagged/userform) have been expanded to include a relevant [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)/[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)/[etc](/questions/tagged/etc).

---

**Update:**

Apparently, the [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) tag has been obliterated, as the `/info` page no longer exists. Can this get a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: Uncommon (low number of question) doesn't make a reason for removal. The thing I'm more concerned about is whether they are useful or not.

Comment: I agree to some point, but I couldn't give you a clear threshold. However, I would argue the tags aren't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UserForm` is an Excel VBA object, and the majority of [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), and [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) questions are *not* about `UserForms`, I think you should leave it. If `UserForm` (or even *form*) was mentioned in almost all of these questions, it would mean it's redundant and that would be a better case for deleting it. That doesn't seem to be the case here. The questions that *are* using this tag are specifically referring to this object.

Retag [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) to [userform](/questions/tagged/userform) (since the object is singular) and remove it from the few questions that are not Excel VBA related.

- [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **× 3,954**
- [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) **+** [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) **‌–** [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **× 2,673** ([result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba+-excel-vba))

Total Excel/VBA Questions: **6,627**

- [userform](/questions/tagged/userform) **× 77**
- [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) **× 15**

Total UserForms Questions: **92 (1.4% of total)**

Questions that are not Excel VBA UserForm related (delete these):

- [userform](/questions/tagged/userform) **‌–** [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) **‌–** [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) **‌–** [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **× 4** ([result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-excel+-vba+-excel-vba+userform))
- [userforms](/questions/tagged/userforms) **‌–** [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) **‌–** [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) **‌–** [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **× 3** ([result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-excel+-vba+-excel-vba+userforms))

Comment: I've fixed those questions and updated my post.